# Curve Fit Parameters in Multiple ODE Function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, odeint

I wan't to implement SEIR model of [Effect of delay in diagnosis on transmission of COVID-19](https://www.aimspress.com/MBE/2020/3/2725) (with little modification) using Python [curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) and [odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html). Without `curve_fit`, my code is like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func_ode(y,t,qS,qSq,betaV1,betaV2,beta1,beta2,e1,eta1,eta2,etaH,delta2,deltaH,theta2,f1,f2,fH,d):

    S_q,S,E1,E2,H,R,D,V=y

    dSq=qS*S-qSq*S_q
    dS=qSq*S_q-(betaV1*V+betaV2*V+beta1*E1+beta2*E2)*S
    dE1=(betaV1*V+beta1*E1)*S-(e1+eta1)*E1
    dE2=(betaV2*V+beta2*E2)*S+e1*E1-(eta2+delta2+theta2)*E2
    dH=theta2*E2-(etaH+deltaH)*H # theta is for recovered
    dR=eta1*E1+eta2*E2+etaH*H # eta is for recovered
    dD=delta2*E2+deltaH*H # delta is for death
    dV=f1*E1+f2*E2+fH*H-d*V 

    dy=[dSq, dS, dE1, dE2, dH, dR, dD, dV]
    return dy

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ## Parameters (dummy)
    qS, qSq, betaV1, betaV2, beta1, beta2, e1, eta1, eta2, etaH, delta2, deltaH, theta2, f1, f2, fH, d = \
        0, 1e-4, 4e-9, 1e-9, 4e-9, 1e-9, 1/100, 1/21, 1/104, 1/10, 1/200, 1/10400, 1/3.5, 1400, 1000, 1700, 144

    ## Initial (dummy)
    y_0=[1000,100000000,10,1,0,0,0,100]

    ## Solve
    t= np.linspace(1,60,60)
    result=odeint(func_ode,y_0,t,args=(qS,qSq,betaV1,betaV2,beta1,beta2,e1,eta1,eta2,etaH,delta2,deltaH,theta2,f1,f2,fH,d))

    ## Plot
    plt.plot(t, result[:, 0], label='Sq')
    plt.plot(t, result[:, 1], label='S')
    plt.plot(t, result[:, 2], label='E1')
    plt.plot(t, result[:, 3], label='E2')
    plt.plot(t, result[:, 4], label='H')
    plt.plot(t, result[:, 5], label='R')
    plt.plot(t, result[:, 6], label='D')
    plt.plot(t, result[:, 7], label='V')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.xlabel('t')
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
    pass
```

To use optimized parameters with input data, this is my *not working* code:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import os
import pandas as pd

def func_ode(y,t,qS,qSq,betaV1,betaV2,beta1,beta2,e1,eta1,eta2,etaH,delta2,deltaH,theta2,f1,f2,fH,d):

    S_q,S,E1,E2,H,R,D,V=y

    dSq=qS*S-qSq*S_q
    dS=qSq*S_q-(betaV1*V+betaV2*V+beta1*E1+beta2*E2)*S
    dE1=(betaV1*V+beta1*E1)*S-(e1+eta1)*E1
    dE2=(betaV2*V+beta2*E2)*S+e1*E1-(eta2+delta2+theta2)*E2
    dH=theta2*E2-(etaH+deltaH)*H # theta is for recovered
    dR=eta1*E1+eta2*E2+etaH*H # eta is for recovered
    dD=delta2*E2+deltaH*H # delta is for death
    dV=f1*E1+f2*E2+fH*H-d*V 

    dy=[dSq, dS, dE1, dE2, dH, dR, dD, dV]
    return dy

def func_y(t,qS,qSq,betaV1,betaV2,beta1,beta2,e1,eta1,eta2,etaH,delta2,deltaH,theta2,f1,f2,fH,d,y_0):
    """
    Solution to the ODE y'(t) = f(t,y,parameters) with initial condition y(0) = y_0
    """
    y = odeint(func_ode, y_0, t, args=(qS,qSq,betaV1,betaV2,beta1,beta2,e1,eta1,eta2,etaH,delta2,deltaH,theta2,f1,f2,fH,d))
    return y[1:,:]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_name='Data Dummy.xlsx'
    current_path=os.getcwd()
    file_path=os.path.join(current_path,file_name)
    sheet_name='Sheet1'

    df_raw=pd.read_excel(file_path,sheet_name=sheet_name)
    numpy_data=df_raw[[
        'Self-quarantine susceptible',
        'Susceptible',
        'E1 (OTG)',
        'E2 (ODP)',
        'H (Hospitalized: PDP + Positif)',
        'R (Sembuh)',
        'D (Meninggal)',
        'V (Virus)'
    ]].to_numpy()               

    ## Parameters (dummy)
    qS, qSq, betaV1, betaV2, beta1, beta2, e1, eta1, eta2, etaH, delta2, deltaH, theta2, f1, f2, fH, d = \
        0, 1e-4, 4e-9, 1e-9, 4e-9, 1e-9, 1/100, 1/21, 1/104, 1/10, 1/200, 1/10400, 1/3.5, 1400, 1000, 1700, 144

    # Used Data
    y_0=numpy_data[0,:].tolist()
    numpy_data=numpy_data[1:60,:]

    ## Reference Time
    number_of_reference_time,_=np.shape(numpy_data)

    ## Solve
    param = qS, qSq, betaV1, betaV2, beta1, beta2, e1, eta1, eta2, etaH, delta2, deltaH, theta2, f1, f2, fH, d, y_0
    t= np.linspace(1,number_of_reference_time,number_of_reference_time)
    popt, cov = curve_fit(func_y, t, numpy_data,p0=[param])

    qS,qSq,betaV1,betaV2,beta1,beta2,e1,eta1,eta2,etaH,delta2,deltaH,theta2,f1,f2,fH,d = popt

    ## Check Result
    result=odeint(func_ode,y_0,t,args=(qS,qSq,betaV1,betaV2,beta1,beta2,e1,eta1,eta2,etaH,delta2,deltaH,theta2,f1,f2,fH,d))

    ## Plot
    plt.plot(t, result[:, 0], label='Sq')
    plt.plot(t, result[:, 1], label='S')
    plt.plot(t, result[:, 2], label='E1')
    plt.plot(t, result[:, 3], label='E2')
    plt.plot(t, result[:, 4], label='H')
    plt.plot(t, result[:, 5], label='R')
    plt.plot(t, result[:, 6], label='D')
    plt.plot(t, result[:, 7], label='V')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.xlabel('t')
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
    pass
```

The error result shows:

```
File "...\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 458, in func_wrapped
    return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (58,8) (59,8)
```

It seems that `curve_fit` can't fit `odeint` that has multiple graphs? Or I miss something here?

Edit:
I edit fixed `y[1:,:]` into `y.flatten()` and `popt, cov = curve_fit(func_y, t, numpy_data,p0=[param])` into `popt, cov = curve_fit(func_y, t, numpy_data.flatten(),p0=[param])`. Also, change the input into `numpy.array(list)` The code can be seen in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/kiFta2TS). Now the problem become:

```py
File "....py", line 164, in <module>
    popt, cov = curve_fit(func_y, t, numpy_data.flatten(),p0=[param])
  File "...\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 752, in curve_fit  
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
  File "...\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 396, in leastsq    
    gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems: First, the error message is saying that the two arrays `ydata` and `func(xdata, *params)` are of different shape:   (59, 8) and (58, 8).   That might be because your `func_y` does:

```
 return y[1:,:]
```

But also: you will probably need to "flatten" your `y` data and the result from the model function to be 1-dimensional (472 observations),  so that you have `func_y` do:

```
 return y.flatten()
```

and you run `curve_fit` with

```
 popt, cov = curve_fit(func_y, t, numpy_data.flatten(), p0=[param])
```

But, there is another conceptual problem that (AFAIK) `curve_fit` cannot handle.  It appears that the final argument of your function `func_y()`, `y_0` is an 8-element array, and meant to be the lower bound on the ODE integration, and *not* meant to be a variable parameter in the curve fitting.   `curve_fit` expects the 1st argument of the model function to be a 1-d array of "independent variable" (here, `t`) and all arguments to be scalar quantities that will become variables in the fit.

When you do

param = qS, qSq, betaV1, betaV2, beta1, beta2, e1, eta1, eta2, etaH, delta2, deltaH, theta2, f1, f2, fH, d, y_0

you are making a tuple that has your 17 variables and 1 8-element array of `y_0`.   `curve_fit` will do `numpy.array(param)` on that, expecting each element of `param` to be a scalar.  With the last element being a list or array, this yields an object array which gives the error message you see.

For better organization of parameters and fit results, including named parameters that can easily be fixed or given bounds, and advanced methods for exploring uncertainties in parameter values and predictions, you might consider using `lmfit` (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/).  In particular, `lmfit.Model` is a class for curve fitting that will identify your function arguments by name. Importantly for your example, it allows multiple independent variables and allows those independent variables to be of any Python type (not restricted to 1d arrays).  `lmfit.Model` also does the flattening for you.   With `lmfit`, your example code would look like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model

def func_ode(y,t,qS,qSq,betaV1,betaV2,beta1,beta2,e1,
             eta1,eta2,etaH,delta2,deltaH,theta2,f1,f2,fH,d):

    Sq,S,E1,E2,H,R,D,V=y

    dSq=qS*S-qSq*Sq
    dS=qSq*Sq-(betaV1*V+betaV2*V+beta1*E1+beta2*E2)*S
    dE1=(betaV1*V+beta1*E1)*S-(e1+eta1)*E1
    dE2=(betaV2*V+beta2*E2)*S+e1*E1-(eta2+delta2+theta2)*E2
    dH=theta2*E2-(etaH+deltaH)*H # theta is for recovered
    dR=eta1*E1+eta2*E2+etaH*H # eta is for recovered
    dD=delta2*E2+deltaH*H # delta is for death
    dV=f1*E1+f2*E2+fH*H-d*V

    dy=[dSq, dS, dE1, dE2, dH, dR, dD, dV]
    return dy

numpy_data=np.array([....  ]) # taken from your pastebin example

def func_y(t, qS, qSq, betaV1, betaV2, beta1, beta2, e1, eta1, 
           eta2, etaH, delta2, deltaH, theta2, f1, f2, fH, d, y_0):
    """
    Solution to the ODE y'(t) = f(t, y, parameters) with 
    initial condition y(0) = y_0
    """
    return  odeint(func_ode, y_0, t, args=(qS, qSq, betaV1, betaV2,
                                           beta1, beta2, e1, eta1,
                                           eta2, etaH, delta2, deltaH,
                                           theta2, f1, f2, fH, d))


y_0 = numpy_data[0,:].tolist()
numpy_data = numpy_data[1:60,:]
number_of_reference_time, _ = np.shape(numpy_data)
t = np.linspace(1, number_of_reference_time, number_of_reference_time)

# create a model from your function, identifying the names of the 
# independent variables (arguments to not treat as variables in the fit)
omodel = Model(func_y, independent_vars=['t', 'y_0'])

# make parameters for this model, using the argument names from 
# your model function
params = omodel.make_params(qS=0, qSq=1e-4, betaV1=4e-9, betaV2=1e-9,
                            beta1=4e-9, beta2=1e-9, e1=1/100,
                            eta1=1/21, eta2=1/104, etaH=1/10,
                            delta2=1/200, deltaH=1/10400, theta2=1/3.5,
                            f1=1400, f2=1000, fH=1700, d=144)

# do the fit to `data` with `parameters` and passing in the 
# independent variables explicitly
result = omodel.fit(numpy_data, params, t=t, y_0=y_0)

# print out fit statistics, best fit values, estimated uncertainties
# note: best fit parameters will be in `result.params['qS']`, etc
print(result.fit_report(min_correl=0.5))

# Plot the portions of the best fit results
plt.plot(t, result.best_fit[:, 0], label='Sq')
plt.plot(t, result.best_fit[:, 1], label='S')
plt.plot(t, result.best_fit[:, 2], label='E1')
plt.plot(t, result.best_fit[:, 3], label='E2')
plt.plot(t, result.best_fit[:, 4], label='H')
plt.plot(t, result.best_fit[:, 5], label='R')
plt.plot(t, result.best_fit[:, 6], label='D')
plt.plot(t, result.best_fit[:, 7], label='V')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

This will print out a report of

```
[[Model]]
    Model(func_y)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 162
    # data points      = 472
    # variables        = 17
    chi-square         = 4.1921e+18
    reduced chi-square = 9.2134e+15
    Akaike info crit   = 17367.1373
    Bayesian info crit = 17437.8060
[[Variables]]
    qS:     -0.01661105 +/- 0.00259955 (15.65%) (init = 0)
    qSq:     1.2272e-04 +/- 2.5428e-05 (20.72%) (init = 0.0001)
    betaV1:  4.5773e-09 +/- 6.9243e-10 (15.13%) (init = 4e-09)
    betaV2:  7.6846e-10 +/- 1.7084e-10 (22.23%) (init = 1e-09)
    beta1:   1.3770e-10 +/- 8.4682e-12 (6.15%) (init = 4e-09)
    beta2:   6.0831e-10 +/- 1.1471e-10 (18.86%) (init = 1e-09)
    e1:      0.04271070 +/- 0.00378279 (8.86%) (init = 0.01)
    eta1:    0.00182043 +/- 3.7579e-04 (20.64%) (init = 0.04761905)
    eta2:   -0.01052990 +/- 5.4028e-04 (5.13%) (init = 0.009615385)
    etaH:    0.12337818 +/- 0.01710376 (13.86%) (init = 0.1)
    delta2:  0.00644283 +/- 5.9399e-04 (9.22%) (init = 0.005)
    deltaH:  9.0316e-05 +/- 4.1630e-05 (46.09%) (init = 9.615385e-05)
    theta2:  0.22640213 +/- 0.06697444 (29.58%) (init = 0.2857143)
    f1:      447.226564 +/- 88.1621816 (19.71%) (init = 1400)
    f2:     -240.442614 +/- 30.5435276 (12.70%) (init = 1000)
    fH:      3780.95590 +/- 543.897368 (14.39%) (init = 1700)
    d:       173.743295 +/- 24.3128286 (13.99%) (init = 144)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.500)
    C(qS, deltaH)     = -0.889
    C(etaH, theta2)   = -0.713
    C(betaV1, f1)     = -0.692
    C(beta1, beta2)   = -0.681
    C(betaV2, etaH)   = -0.673
    C(qS, eta2)       = -0.652
    C(deltaH, d)      = -0.651
    C(betaV1, theta2) =  0.646
    C(f1, d)          =  0.586
    C(eta2, deltaH)   =  0.585
    C(betaV2, d)      =  0.582
    C(qSq, betaV1)    = -0.523
    C(betaV2, f1)     =  0.510
```

and make a plot like this:

[image]

I don't know if that is the best fit you were looking for, but I hope it helps get you started.

Comment: Thank you, but the error is changing: ```File "...\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 396, in leastsq    
    gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'```

Whose type is wrong here?

p.s. I'll try to check limfit tho.

Comment: dtype('O') means "object array", meaning it could not easily convert all of the Pandas data to numpy arrays.  You'll want to check each of the elements to make sure they are valid numerical data or omit them from the data (scipy.optimize simply cannot deal with non-numeric data).

Comment: I edit the data into `numpy.array(list])` and the problem still persist. It seems the problem comes from the packing odeint into `curve_fit`. Here is my code in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/kiFta2TS). Can you find where the problem actually came from?

Comment: ok, I see another problem in your code: is `y_0` intended to be a variable parameter in the fit or "extra data" to `func_y()` as the lower limit of the integral?  For `curve_fit` the `params` must be strictly a 1-d array of scalar values corresponding to the function arguments. Casting a list with an embedded list to a numpy array will also create an object array.     I will update my answer, using lmfit, to avoind this problem.

Comment: `y_0` is value that I want to be passed to `odeint` since `odeint` need a starting point (AFAIK). I thought that I should place it there. I'm trying to understand `lmfit` but can't find the example to do it for `odeint` yet. Thank you very much for the `lmfit` implementation to solve `odeint`.

Comment: I remove `y_0` from the curve_fit input, but it still need to be delcared as global. But, there is warning `ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
  warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning)`. Do you know what is that (although the resulted graph and parameter is shown)?

Comment: %his kind of is an example using `odeint`. Or: for `lmfit` there is nothing special about `odeint`.  There is a model function `func_y` to calculate an nd-array (here 2D) that should have its parameters adjusted until it matches some data.   Sure, call `odeint` or do some FFTs or whatever inside that function.  Sure, have a couple of function arguments identified as independent parameters ("not fitting parameters") to help you do the model calculation.  I don't know what that ODEIntWarning means.